# $1 in regular expression javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

when I use `var j= new RegExp('('+val+')','gi')` then `$1` works fine. but when I am using it without bracket then it is not working. So I want to know why brackets is necessary and does `$1` hold the value which have to be replaced?

```
var val='city'
var j= new RegExp('('+val+')','gi')
console.log(j)
$('div').html(function(i,val){
return val.replace(j,'<span>$1</span>')
})
```

Comment: `()` are parentheses, not brackets.

Comment: The [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_string_as_a_parameter) has it all :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`$n` is replaced by the part of the string that matched the `n`th capture group in the regexp. Capture groups are the parts of the regular expression in parentheses. If you don't have any parentheses, there are no capture groups, so `$1` won't be replaced with anything.

If you want the match for the entire regexp, use `$&`.

Answer (score 1):

By brackets, do you mean paranthesis?

If so, paranthesis denote a [capture group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html) in regex, which means that the content inside is captured.

If you need help accessing captured groups you can look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/432493/how-do-you-access-the-matched-groups-in-a-javascript-regular-expression), which explains it quite thoroughly.

Answer (score 0):

Parentheses are used to form capturing groups in regular expressions. See more details here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html

Note that in order to match the parentheses, you have to escape them.